# showing sub menu out of menu item when the menu has a vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Am trying to create a menu which would be on the left side of a 2 column layout.
The menu is positioned as fixed and it has a specific height so that those menu items that are overflowing could be seen with a vertical scroll bar.

But am struggling to pop out the sub menu items out of the menu item using a pure css solution without any javascript.

what i have tried is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nataraj_gnanavadivel/npwro63c/

```
.left-navigation {
  position: fixed;
  height: 86%;
  background: rgba(254, 228, 194, 0.3);
  width: 24%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: block;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.menu-item {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  position: static;
  display: inline-block;
}

.sub-menu-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid red 1px;
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

The submenu contents are still staying inside the leftnavigation div inside the scroll bar.

It should come out of that container and displayed against the menu item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you want to use `overflow-y: auto` and `overflow-x: visible` in the same elements, which [according to the specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-box/#overflow-x) are not possible to use together (`overflow-x` becomes `auto`).

What you need to do is to separate the behavior into two elements, the first one will show the scrollbar, and the second one will show the overflowed elements.

[See this working approach in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fjphwbL/)

Changes:

- I modified your HTML and added a `<div class="items-container">` between the navigation and the items.
- Modified the CSS and added:

  .items-container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
  }

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: could you please update the jsfiddle link. It's showing the css spec.

Comment: I tried yours. It's working cool. Thanks a lot for your time and efforts. I appreicate it a lot.

Comment: have just updated my jsfiddle too with the suggested solution.. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nataraj_gnanavadivel/npwro63c/)

Comment: @Nataraj my mistake, I've updated the JSFiddle link, thanks for pointing this out!